# Wordpress @include( 'template-config.php' );

Tags: php, errors

[image: website screenshot]

I'm new to WordPress and I'm getting this message on my WordPress website

**@include( 'template-config.php' );**

I can't access my wp-admin page and website either both of them giving me the same page, I also tried wp-login.php but that showed me "**Error: Cookies are blocked due to unexpected output. For help, please see this documentation or try the support forums.**"

I can only access my files through cPanel so is there a way to fix it? if not is it possible to reset my website and reinstall WordPress to rebuild the website

Website URL: **irindia.org**

Answer (score 1):

Something in your theme is not written properly. I can't tell you what it is exactly as I don't know what your code is.

Seeing as that code is supposed to be php, and is being shown on your page, I am going to assume that there is no `<?php ?>` tags around it, and it is being shown as if it is text as the theme does not know it's supposed to be php.

Check your error log on your server to get an idea of where the issue is.

What you should do to get access to your site again is in CPanel, rename your active theme's folder to something else (wp-content/themes/yourtheme/). This will manually deactivate the theme. If the issue is the theme itself, you will be able to access the backend of your site.

Comment: file name error_log.log is empty and I tried changing the name of the themes, but nothing changes. any other way? if not can u help me with restarting this site from the start so I can rebuild it with WordPress again

Answer (score -1):

You are under attack by a backdoor named “DynDoor”. It makes a file named "template-config.php" in your (maybe not just) woodmart theme and then by including it in "functions.php" runs some code when visiting your site.

I am challenging with it currently and will be happy if someone gave us more information.

([maybe useful link](https://blog.curohosting.com/how-to-stop-those-really-stubborn-viruses-from-your-wordpress-website/))